# 2 returns firing in the same function?

Tags: java, if-statement, return-value

Well been working for hours today so i might be missing something silly, but, at this point I'm kinda blind with this and looking for an explanation for this behaviour

i made an example of the problem I'm having and the solution i found is not quite a solution.

The Problem: to the following function I pass 1 as shotCount and 9 as Countdown
the result when i debug, i see the first if run, and run the return 2, but then also the else decides to run to and finally return -1

```
    public int getNextShot(int shotCount, int Countdown)
    {
        if ((shotCount == 1) && (Countdown != 10)) return 2;
        else if (shotCount == 0) return 1;
        else return -1;
    }
```

BUT if i do this (same parameters) it works:

```
   public int getNextShot(int shotCount, int Countdown)
    {
        int res = -2;
        if ((shotCount == 1) && (Countdown != 10))  res = 2;
        else if (shotCount == 0) res = 1;
        else res = -1;
        return res;
    }
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you not using curly brackets?

Comment: Post the code calling this method, and why you think you have "2 returns firing" (which is not possible in Java, at least as described).

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the breakpoints at the right places?  Maybe you're accidentally skipping over your one of your return statements while continuing code execution in the debugger, and actually getting a 2nd invocation of your function?  Try splitting up the returns to their own lines, and setting break-points on all the lines. (and as Oleg said - use curly braces!  This is one of the reasons to *always* include them)

Comment: did you wrap with `try{ .. } finally { return -1; }` block?

Comment: @John: There is nothing that will throw an exception here.  The OP could try it, but it's totally a shot in the dark.  Such code should *not* be left in.

Comment: @Merlyn: no catch block. it's all about finally block with return value if any

Comment: Hey you have put the condition and the return commands on the same line ,probabely thats the reason you are feeling that two returns are being fired while debugging.I don't think java can return more than single value...Use proper coding conventions

Comment: @Everyone: I think is something with the Eclipse debugger as stated by Kai in one of the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are mistaken.

Sometimes the debugger in Eclipse acts like its jumping to the last line of the method call but then does return the correct value.

For example, I just copied and pasted your code and it ran fine for me. The below code prints 2.

```
public class AA {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                System.out.println(getNextShot(1, 9));

        }

        public static int getNextShot(int shotCount, int Countdown)
    {
        if ((shotCount == 1) && (Countdown != 10)) return 2;
        else if (shotCount == 0) return 1;
        else return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: That usually happens because the compiler does some optimizations (don't know about eclipse-java, but it's quite common for android).

Comment: I think you are right, but before giving you as the best answer, i wanna run one more test. Is late now i will run it tomorrow. and let you know, because i saw what you are saying but i think there are times it actually takes the second return value.

Comment: Also i wanna add if code like in the second case I showed is used, this strange behavior doesn't show up, only saw it when using multiple returns.

Comment: I don't know what the problem was , maybe i was working for so long that i just saw something wrong and something else was failing on my debugging , anyways, i tested again, debbuged, and yes, it acts as you say. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code is OK. When I run this:

```
public static int getNextShot1(int shotCount, int Countdown) {
    if ((shotCount == 1) && (Countdown != 10)) {
        return 2;
    } else if (shotCount == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
public static int getNextShot2(int shotCount, int Countdown) {
    int res = -2;
    if ((shotCount == 1) && !(Countdown == 10)) {
        res = 2;
    } else if (shotCount == 0) {
        res = 1;
    } else {
        res = -1;
    }
    return res;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws KeyStoreException, ParseException {
    System.out.println(getNextShot1(1, 9));
    System.out.println(getNextShot2(1, 9));

}
```

I get

```
2
2
```

on console :)
Second function could look like this (final keyword):

```
public static int getNextShot2(int shotCount, int Countdown) {
    final int res;
    if ((shotCount == 1) && !(Countdown == 10)) {
        res = 2;
    } else if (shotCount == 0) {
        res = 1;
    } else {
        res = -1;
    }
    return res;
}
```